# How to properly canalize multithreaded message flow in a single threaded service?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

In a WPF application, I have a 3rd party library that is publishing messages.

The messages are like :

```
public class DialectMessage
{
    public string PathAndQuery { get; private set; }

    public byte[] Body { get; private set; }

    public DialectMessage(string pathAndQuery, byte[] body)
    {
        this.PathAndQuery = pathAndQuery;
        this.Body = body;
    }
}
```

And I setup the external message source from my app.cs file :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        MyComponent.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
        MyComponent.Start();
    }

    private static void MessageReceived(Message message)
    {
        //handle message
    }

}
```

These messages can be publishing from multiple thread at a time, making possible to call the event handler multiple times at once.

I have a service object that have to parse the incoming messages. This service implements the following interface :

```
internal interface IDialectService
{
    void Parse(Message message);
}
```

And I have a default static instance in my app.cs file :

```
    private readonly static IDialectService g_DialectService = new DialectService();
```

In order to simplify the code of the parser, I would like to ensure only one message at a time is parsed.

I also want to avoid locking in my event handler, as I don't want to block the 3rd party object.

Because of this requirements, I cannot directly call `g_DialectService.Parse` from my message event handler

**What is the correct way to ensure this single threaded execution?**

My first though is to wrap my parsing operations in a Produce/Consumer pattern. In order to reach this goal, I've try the following :

1. Declare a BlockingCollection in my app.cs :

   ```
   private readonly static BlockingCollection<Message> g_ParseOperations = new BlockingCollection<Message>();
   ```
2. Change the body of my event handler to add an operation :

   ```
   private static void MessageReceived(Message message)
   {
       g_ParseOperations.Add(message);
   }
   ```
3. Create a new thread that pump the collection from my app constructor :

   ```
   static App()
   {
       MyComponent.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
       MyComponent.Start();

       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           Message message;
           while (g_ParseOperations.TryTake(out message))
           {
               g_DialectService.Parse(message);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

However, this code does not seems to work. The service Parse method is never called.

Moreover, I'm not sure if this pattern will allow me to properly shutdown the application.

**What have I to change in my code to ensure everything is working?**

PS: I'm targeting .Net 4.5

**[Edit] After some search, and [the answer of ken2k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579111/588868), i can see that I was wrongly calling trytake in place of take**.

My updated code is now :

```
    private readonly static CancellationTokenSource g_ShutdownToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private static void MessageReceived(Message message)
    {
        g_ParseOperations.Add(message, g_ShutdownToken.Token);
    }

    static App()
    {
        MyComponent.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
        MyComponent.Start();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!g_ShutdownToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var message = g_ParseOperations.Take(g_ShutdownToken.Token);
                g_DialectService.Parse(message);
            }
        });
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        g_ShutdownToken.Cancel();
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
```

This code acts as expected. Messages are processed in the correct order. However, as soon I exit the application, I get a "CancelledException" on the Take method, even if I just test the IsCancellationRequested right before.

Comment: So?  You are closing the app - just eat the exception!

Comment: ..or, even better, don't bother cancelling the thread at all.

Comment: This may works as I'm actually exiting the application. But for my personal knowledge, I'd like to know how to properly shutdown (imagine a start/stop pair of buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184.aspx) says about `BlockingCollection.TryTake(out T item)`:

> If the collection is empty, this method immediately returns false.

So basically your loop exits immediately. What you may want is to call the [TryTake method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287154.aspx) with a timeout parameter instead, and exit your loop when a `mustStop` variable becomes `true`:

```
bool mustStop = false;  // Must be set to true on somewhere else when you exit your program
...
while (!mustStop)
{
    Message yourMessage;

    // Waits 500ms if there's nothing in the collection. Avoid to consume 100% CPU
    // for nothing in the while loop when the collection is empty.
    if (yourCollection.TryTake(out yourMessage, 500))
    {
        // Parses yourMessage here
    }
}
```

---

For your edited question: if you mean you received a `OperationCanceledException`, that's OK, it's exactly how methods that take a `CancellationToken` object as parameter must behave :) Just catch the exception and exit gracefully.

Comment: I've seen that after posting. Let me update my question, there are still some issues.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I cannot simply check my cancellationtokensource.Iscancellationrequested. Because, this checks is done before the cancelation actually occurs. Most of time, the Take method will be in wait state. I've added a simple try/catch(OperationCancelledException) and that works. thx